# Angular 7, how can I control ng-select options by selecting other ng-select value?

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have two ng-select in my code, and if I select first ng-select value, I want to hide the same select option from the second ng-select. But I dont know how to control it. I wanted to use Jquery with, but no chance.
Both sourceLangCodeList and targetLangCodeList has values [ EN, KR ]
So the thing I want to try, once I select the value of one of ng-select, hide the same value the second ng-select has. Plz help!

```
<td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <ng-select
                  id="sourceLangSelect"
                  bindLabel="language"
                  bindValue="language"
                  formControlName="sourceLangCode"
                  [items]="sourceLangCodeList"
                  (change)="onChange($event)"
                ></ng-select>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <ng-select
                  id="targetLangSelect"
                  bindLabel="language"
                  bindValue="language"
                  formControlName="targetLangCode"
                  [items]="targetLangCodeList"
                ></ng-select>
              </div>
            </td>
```

Comment: @RahulCv got a good answer using the (change) event binding. but since you are using reactive formControls , please see my answer which might help in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Please add a ngModel to slectedSoureclang and Onchange Filter the targetLangCodeList

```
                 <ng-select
              id="sourceLangSelect"
              bindLabel="language"
              bindValue="language"
              formControlName="sourceLangCode"
              [items]="sourceLangCodeList"
              (change)="onChange($event)"
              [(ngModel)]="selectedSourceLang"
            ></ng-select>
```

Change Event

```
  onChange(event){
                        
                        const newlist = targetLangCodeList.filter((lang)=>lang!==this.selectedSourceLang);
                        targetLangCodeList = [...newlist];
    
                      }
```

Comment: ```
It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7.
    
    For more information on this, see our API docs here:
    https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel
```
Angular7 doesnt support ngModel anymore, so I didnt use exactly, but your change event helped! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ReactiveForms, I will answer in ReactiveForm way.
Check out the full code at https://stackblitz.com/edit/m3yevn-ng-select-demo

Template:

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <ng-select id="sourceLangSelect" bindLabel="language" bindValue="language" formControlName="sourceLangCode"
        [items]="sourceLangCodeList"></ng-select>
    <ng-select id=" targetLangSelect" bindLabel="language" bindValue="language" formControlName="targetLangCode"
        [items]="targetLangCodeList"></ng-select>
</div>
```

Component

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "ng-select-demo",
  templateUrl: "./ng-select-demo.component.html",
  styles: [
    `
      h1 {
        font-family: Lato;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class NgSelectDemo {
  @Input() name: string;
  sub = new Subscription();

  originalLangCodeList = [
    { language: "" },
    { language: "en" },
    { language: "kr" },
    { language: "zh-cn" },
    { language: "ru" }
  ];
  targetLangCodeList = [...this.originalLangCodeList];
  sourceLangCodeList = [...this.originalLangCodeList];

  formGroup = new FormGroup({
    sourceLangCode: new FormControl(""),
    targetLangCode: new FormControl("")
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub.add(
      this.formGroup.controls["sourceLangCode"].valueChanges.subscribe(
        value => {
          this.targetLangCodeList = this.originalLangCodeList.filter(
            langObj => langObj.language !== value
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

TLDR;

- Use a form group to create two formControlName which you are apparently using.
- In ngOnInit, subscribe the valueChanges of formGroup.controls['sourceLangCode'].
- When value changes, filter the language which have been selected in targetLangCode.
- In ngOnDestroy, don't forget to unsubscribe it.

Comment: Thank you for kind answer! I will try this too.

Comment: @pearllv no problem. anytime for a fellow dev